# Mysql query deducting two fields from different table

Tags: mysql

I want to achieve a query that resulting a students (based on search) with total amount balance from assessment table minus payment table.

---

student_name - spent(assessment) - paid(payment) - total_balance

---

table 1: **students**
id, firstname, lastname, middlename, idno

```
Sample Data
1, a, a, a, 18001
2, b, b, b, 18002
```

table 2: **assessment**
id, studentid, amount

```
Sample Data
1, 1, 500
2, 1, 600
3, 2, 100
4, 2, 100
```

table 3: **payment**
id, studentid, amount

```
Sample Data
1, 1, 200
2, 1, 100
```

---

RESULT MUST BE:

```
student, assessment, payment, balance
a, 1100, 200, 900
b, 200, 100, 100
```

---

This is my current query now... and didn't give result as I expected.

```
$qry = "SELECT c.*, SUM(CASE WHEN x.type = 'assessment' THEN x.amount ELSE 0 END) spent
                             , SUM(CASE WHEN x.type = 'payments' THEN x.amount ELSE 0 END) paid
                             , SUM(CASE WHEN x.type = 'assessment' THEN x.amount ELSE x.amount * -1 END) total
                          FROM students c
                          LEFT JOIN 
                             ( SELECT studentid
                                    , 'assessment' type
                                    , amount
                                 FROM assessment 
                                UNION
                               SELECT studentid
                                    , 'payments'
                                    , amount
                                 FROM payment 
                             ) x
                            ON x.studentid = c.id
                         WHERE ((c.firstname like '%$search%' or c.lastname like '%$search%' or c.middlename like '%$search%' or c.idno like '%$search%') and c.status = 1)
                         GROUP
                            BY c.id;";
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, I just update first post with sample table and data.

Comment: There is no payment record for student 2, How in your expected output you are showing payment as 100 ?

Answer (score 0):

Perform sum of amounts from each table for each students in individual sub clauses and then join these clauses with your main query

```
SELECT c.*,
  COALESCE(a.amount,0) assessment,
  COALESCE(p.amount,0) payment,
  COALESCE(a.amount,0) - COALESCE(p.amount,0) balance
FROM students c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT studentid, SUM(amount) amount 
           FROM assessment
           GROUP BY studentid
) a ON c.id = a.studentid
LEFT JOIN(SELECT studentid, SUM(amount) amount
          FROM payment
          GROUP BY studentid         
) p ON c.id = p.studentid
WHERE ((c.firstname like '%$search%' 
        OR c.lastname like '%$search%' 
        OR c.middlename like '%$search%' 
        OR c.idno like '%$search%') 
       AND c.status = 1)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63736c/2)